# How to use try except in case of a dictionary with multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-3.5, try-except

I am using parallel processing to generate a dictionary as the following:

```
def transform(x):
    result = {'name': x.name, 'result_cap1': NLTK.parser(cap1), 
            'result_cap2': NLTK.parser(cap2)}  

    return result


final_result = tuple(map(transform, mylist))
```

But the problem is something may go wrong with the `NLTK.parser()` so for that particular value I want to change it to `" "`. I was able to come up with something like this:

```
def transform(x):
    try:
        result = {'name': x.name, 'result_cap1': NLTK.parser(cap1), 
                'result_cap2': NLTK.parser(cap2)}  
    except Exception:
        result = {'name': x.name, 'result_cap1': " ", 
                'result_cap2': " "}

    return result
```

But the problem is I am not sure if the error was because of `cap1` or `cap2`, so I am assigning both of them to `" "`. How to assign `" "` to the value that cause the error only?

Comment: Do it in two steps…!? `result = {'name': x.name}; try: result['result_cap1'] = ...; ...`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But if I do it in 2 steps will the parallel processing still working? I heard it is always to do only 1 thing and use `lambda`. Also would you please write your answer as a comment, I am not sure how to do it as you said! Thanks again!

Comment: There's no "parallel processing" going on here that I can see.

Comment: Yes it would work in the same fashion as answers have suggested. It is just like checking for exception at each step

Answer (score 2):

Just do it in two steps, like this:

```
def transform(x):
    result = {'name': x.name};
    try:
       result['result_cap1'] = NLTK.parser(cap1)
    except:
        result['result_cap1'] = " "
    try:
        result['result_cap2'] = NLTK.parser(cap2)
    except:
        result['result_cap2'] = " "

    return result
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But in case of my dictionary contains 100 values, then I have to create 100 try catch? Just wondering

Answer (score 1):

Put your exception handlers around the `NLTK.parser()` calls *separately*, by assigning their results to variables first:

```
try:
    result_cap1 = NLTK.parser(cap1)
except Exception:
    result_cap1 = " "

try:
    result_cap2 = NLTK.parser(cap2)
except Exception:
    result_cap2 = " "

result = {'name': x.name, 'result_cap1': result_cap1, 'result_cap2': result_cap2}
```

or you can first create the dictionary (with defaults) and assign to the keys:

```
result = {'name': x.name, 'result_cap1': " ", 'result_cap2': " "}


try:
    result['result_cap1'] = NLTK.parser(cap1)
except Exception:
    pass

try:
    result['result_cap2'] = NLTK.parser(cap2)
except Exception:
    pass
```

You really want to find more specific exceptions to catch, however; surely a more specific `ValueError` or `TypeError` can be caught instead.

You also need to take into account that some NLTK parsers can return a *generator* from a `.parse()` call; if you are to re-use the parser for multiple inputs, you probably want to convert the generator object to a list first.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the amount of repetitious code and follow the software development principle of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I would suggest doing something along these line which utilizes a helper function:

```
def transform(x):

    def parse(cap):
        """ Nested helper function. """
        try:
            result = NLTK.parser(cap)
        except Exception:
            result = " "
        return result

    return {'name': x.name,
            'result_cap1': parse(cap1),
            'result_cap2': parse(cap2)}

final_result = tuple(map(transform, mylist))
```

The helper function doesn't have to be nested inside `transform()`, but doing so make it more obvious it's only being used with that function.

Also note that it's generally a poor programming practice to handle such generic exception in an `except` clause because it can hide problems you probably wouldn't want ignored, such as a `SyntaxError`. In other words, it would be better to be more specific and explicitly state the kind to ignore.